# Printing lines from a file where a specific field is matched

Tags: linux, unix, scripting, sed, awk

I have many lines of form:
A:B:C

I want to print those lines(complete) where the 3rd field (fields separated by :) contain a certain pattern.

Example:

new/old:california/new york:/ms/dist/fx/PROJ/fx/startScript

new/old:startScript/new york:/ms/dist/fx/PROJ/fx/stopScript

When searching for pattern startScript, the 1st line should be printed and not the 2nd one.

Thanks,

Jagrati

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Separate on colon, then check third field:

```
awk -F : '$3 ~ /startScript/ { print }'
```

Answer (score 1):

The general solution is to use awk but it is worth noting that in your specific example there is a much simpler solution - you can just use grep:

```
grep 'startScript$' yourfile
```

Comment: The 3rd field can contain the pattern (startScript in this case) in any form. This was just an example. The pattern may not be prefixed by /ms/dist/fx and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F":" '$3~/startScript$/' file
```